# pyspark udf AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: pyspark

Trying to use simple `udf` inside `withColumn`, i'm getting the below error.

Actually the order number is a string type and it has the value something like this below and it has no null values.

```
1234.345.344343434
```

**code:**

```
order_udf = udf(lambda x: x[x.rfind(".") + 1:], StringType())
df.withColumn("order_number", order_udf('order_number')).show()
```

Do i need to change something on udf call?

Comment: I was able to execute the above code and got ordernumber as `344343434`.

Comment: i too got this when i execute in my local, but in the cluster its not working.. i hope this is something to do with DataType is not getting passed correctly

Comment: ok.. is there specific reason behind using `udf` instead of regular spark functions? like regexp_replace (or) split?

Comment: @Shu: no, i thought of using this is easy? can we use regexp_replace for this? basically i need to get the last part of the order number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can **`split`** the order number on `.` then get the `last element of array` (or) we can use **`regexp_extract`** function to get only the order_number from last `.`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1=sc.parallelize([('1234.345.344343434',)]).toDF(["o"])
df1.withColumn("arr", split(col("o"),'\.')).selectExpr("arr[size(arr)-1] as order_number").show(10,False)

#starting from spark2.4+ we can use element_at function
df1.withColumn("arr", element_at(split(col("o"),'\.'),-1)).show(10,False)

#using regexp_extract function
df1.withColumn("order_number",regexp_extract(col('o'),'(?=[^.]+$)(.*)',1)).show()

#+------------+
#|order_number|
#+------------+
#|344343434   |
#+------------+
```

Comment: why we need to use element_at, why can't we just use `split(col("o"),'\.')[2]`

Comment: @Shankar , if your data always have two ‘.’ In then its okay to use.. to make it more dynamic way we are using -1 then we will always get last element from array!

Answer (score 2):

You can do without udf:(using split and element_at)

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
list=[['1234.345.344343434']]
df=spark.createDataFrame(list,['value'])
df.show()


+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|1234.345.344343434|
+------------------+


df.withColumn("value", F.element_at(F.split("value",'\.'),-1)).show()

+---------+
|value    |
+---------+
|344343434|
+---------+
```